# basic query very slow on azure managed instance sql server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, t-sql, select

On an Azure managed sql server instance database, 
I do

```
Select top 1000 * from _CSP_Detail.
```

The data table is empty because I deleted all data from the table yesterday (Delete * from _CSP_Detail).
It used to have a million rows, and it took a while to delete.  There are a hand full of indexes / indices defined on the table.

After doing the delete, today, I am finding that

```
Select top 1000 * from _CSP_Detail
```

does pull nothing, as expected, 
but takes over a minute to run.

Puzzled.
Any ideas?

Comment: Out of interest why not use `TRUNCATE` instead of `DELETE`? Or were there also Foreign Keys with `CASCADE` enabled?

Comment: Amazing.  After doing truncate, the query works like a charm.  Seems like it is using some resources there.  There must be some sort of command to make the database queries more efficient by compacting the database; sometimes you just want to make it efficient, but not delete all the data......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your table is a heap (no clustered index). Space is not reclaimed when you delete rows from a heap so, even though the table is empty, the allocated pages must be scanned by the `SELECT` query to find rows.

Explicitly `TRUNCATE` the table or create/drop a clustered index to reclaim space and improve performance against the empty table.

Note that tables should generally have a clustered index according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/heaps-tables-without-clustered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: yep!  that's the problem.  I think it is bad to require an index...sometimes, that's just not the nature of the data.  i can create a new arbitrary index field on the table, but I think it is a bad design by Microsoft...

Comment: Is there a command to reclaim without truncate?  Sometimes you just want to make more efficient but not delete the data.

Comment: Yes, create and drop a clustered index as called out in the documentation link I included in my answer. Note that table's primary key is clustered by default unless you specified otherwise. If the table doesn't have a primary key, then it's not a relational table in the traditional sense so it should be no surprise to run into undesired behavior in an RDBMS. That said, I do sometimes use a table for non-relational data (e.g. log) but always create a clustered index.